# How array() parameter works in array_diff() in php?

Tags: php

I have an example like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array(-1,0,1,12,-100,1);
print_r($arr); echo "</br>";
$new_arr = array_diff($arr, array(12));
print_r($new_arr); 
?>
```

The "array()" part ("array(12)" in this example is a "keyword" that can be used to grab a value in an array? This is not explained in the php.net manual, at least not with the array_diff. If you could point me to an explanation it would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: `The "array()" part ("array(12)" in this example is a "keyword" that can be used to grab a value in an array?` Nope!!! `array(12)` means create a new array, and insert a single element with a value of `12`

Comment: The manual is pretty clear about how `array_diff()` works. It's hard to explain it in a better way.

Comment: So you have one array (`$arr`) that you've already created containg a series of elements with the values `-1`,`0`,`1`,`12`,`-100`,and `1`; then yu're creating a second array containing a single element with the value `12`; and calling `array_diff()` to tel you the difference between those two arrays

Comment: `$new_arr` won't have the `12` value because it is present in the second array. All other values from `$arr` will be present.

Comment: *"This is not explained in the php.net manual"* -- yes, it is. There is an entire [page dedicated to it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php). With examples. More examples in the documentation page of [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This last one is linked in the ["Return Values"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-returnvalues) section of the documentation page of `array_diff()`. It links to the first one in its ["Syntax"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array(12) is not a keyword, It is an array declared with only value 12 at index 0. let me re-write and that will be self explanatory.

```
<?php
    $arr = array(-1,0,1,12,-100,1);
    $arr2 = array(12);
    print_r($arr); echo "</br>";
    print_r($arr2); echo "</br>";
    $new_arr = array_diff($arr, $arr2);
    print_r($new_arr); 
?>
```

Comment: yes array is a PHP keyword but array(12) is not something that was perceived by user. According to context, he thought array(12) is some builtin thing in PHP that we use with array_diff.